# How to get header and nav menu on same line

Tags: php, html, css, header, nav

I am trying to get the header of my site and the navigation on the same line.  I want the header to be aligned left and the navigation to be centered.  My code doesn't seem to be working, so I was wondering if anyone has any solutions?  Thanks in advance.

an example of what I am trying to have it look like...
[image]

my header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="container">
<!-- site-header -->
<header class="site-header">
<h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>
     
     <nav class="site-nav">
        <?php 
          wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu' => 'Primary Menu Links', 
            'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
            'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Walker()
          )); 
        ?>
    </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
```

my css

```html
.site-header h1 {
margin: 0;
    font-family: 'futura_tbold';
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
}
/* Drop Down Menu */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
}

#cssmenu {
height: 37px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom:50px;
width: 0 auto;
    margin-right:38px;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover 
}
#cssmenu > ul {
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
list-style: inside none;



position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {

display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 12px 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'textaw00-heavyregular', 'AvenirNextLTW01', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
color: #2f3847;  
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
color:#8F1E3E;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #3d0d1d;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(61, 13, 29, 1);
  content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
border-color: transparent transparent #3d0d1d transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {

    
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a {
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div {
display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
color: #8F1E3E;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul,
#cssmenu ul li > div {
display: none;
width: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 38px;
padding: 10px 0;
background: #490f20;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index: 999;        
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul {
width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li {
display: block;
list-style: inside none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a {
outline: none;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 8px 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'textaw00-heavyregular', 'AvenirNextLTW01', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height:25px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
color: #ffffff;
    background-color:#8F1E3E;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover:before {
border-top: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy hope this helps

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o6hagzz/1/)

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- <img src="#" alt=""> -->
      <span>LOGO</span>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
        <li>Page 4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```